# Capture photo using particular physical camera id, not logical camera id

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

There are many devices which have multiple back cameras. I want to capture a picture using the particular back camera.

There is update by google in Android 9 about [Multi-camera support and camera updates](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#camera) but I didn't find any proper example.

Note: I'm using [Camera2 API](https://github.com/Jiankai-Sun/Android-Camera2-API-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jack/mainactivity/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

In the example source code you gave, they just choose the first camera found :

```
cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
```

You have to change this to get the full list of (logical) cameraId.

For each of these, you can eventually check if there is one or more physical Camera Id associated with the [CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#getCameraCharacteristics(java.lang.String)), which in turn may return the set of physical IDs with [getPhysicalCameraIds method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#getPhysicalCameraIds()).

EDIT :
A code for browsing these values should look like (untested) :

```
  String[] logicalCameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
  for (String logicalCameraId: logicalCameraIds) {
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics( logicalCameraId );
    if ( characteristics.get( CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA ) ) {
      Log.e(TAG, String.format("Camera %s is a logical camera backed by two or more physical cameras", logicalCameraId);
      Set<String> physicalIds = characteristics.getPhysicalCameraIds ();
      for (String physicalId: physicalIds) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Physical camera found : %s", physicalId);
      }
    } else {
      Log.e(TAG, String.format("Camera %s is a simple camera", logicalCameraId);
    }
  }
```

It's up to you to append any logic you need (user choice, ...) to select the desired camera Id (be it logical of physical).

After that, `manager.openCamera(cameraId,...)` can be used.

Comment: I know that two methods but don't know how to apply physical id for capture picture.
Also I have checked getPhysicalCameraIds in many device which have multiple camera and Android P version but always returns empty list.

Comment: I've updated my answer for a way to test your devices. Having multiple camera (back/front) does not mean that you have multiple physical cameras linked to a single logical camera id.